# jQuery Validation Plugin:Position of error messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Doumentation of jQuery Validation Plugin says:
There are four ways to provide error messages.
1、Via the title attribute of the input element to validate;
2、Via data attributes;
3、Via error labels;
4、Via plugin settings (option messages).

Question is about Item 3:
By default, labels are created after the invalid element,
but,when facing radio and checkbox of Bootstrap，error labels are created after the first input of each group，I want to put error labels after the last input of each group,how to do it?

Demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/tether/1.1.1/css/tether.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form id="demo1">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2">Radios</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios1" value="option1">
                    //error label is put here by default
                    Option1
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios2" value="option2">
                    Option2
                </label>
            </div>
            //I want to put the error label here
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2">Checkbox</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="option1">
                //error label is put here by default
                Option1
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox2" value="option2">Option2
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox3" value="option3">Option3
            </label>
            //I want to put the error label here
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/tether/1.1.1/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery-validate/1.14.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#demo1").validate({
            rules: {
                gridRadios: {
                    required: true
                },
                checkbox: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                gridRadios: {
                    required: "required"
                },
                checkbox: {
                    required: "required"
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```